# langchain csvLoader error openai.error.InvalidRequestError: '$.input' is invalid

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am using a simple langchain CSVLoader to load a sample data that I downloaded from [here](https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2021-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2021-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv)

My simple code is here: https://pastebin.com/RNT1bpTM
When I start my script, I get the error:

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: '$.input' is invalid. Please check the API reference: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference.
```

I also tried loading csv with specifying arguments but it's not any better.
Do you know what am I missing? Csv format seems valid.

Thanks

Comment: could you paste the code here, not able to open pastebin

Comment: sorry, the code is too long to be posted in a comment. Here is a pastes.io (maybe it will work better):
https://pastes.io/rayd3pwy8c

Comment: Can i know what the size of the csv?

Comment: yes, the file is 6.6Mb. You can download it by clicking on the link I provided in the description.